# Apache Web Proxy via URL

Tags: apache, proxy

I am looking to setup one of my virtualhost as proxy like lot of proxies on appspot (src https://github.com/bslatkin/mirrorrr), it works like that :

```
http://myproxy.mydomain.com/www.google.com
```

Is there any simple config lines to put on my .conf ?

Tried following, but not working

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproxy.mydomain.com

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.myproxy.log combined

    #ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPassMatch ^(.*)$ "http://$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do your logs say?  You'll have an extra slash in the beginning and be miissing one at the end.

Comment: `ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ "http://$1"` dont work too, no slash at the end, it can be `http://myproxy.mydomain.com/www.site.com/index.php?a=1&b=2#foo`

Comment: nothing useful in logs